# The probability of random strings matching at more than X locations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a problem related to the significance of experimental results, but I will frame it this way:

Suppose I have two binary strings of length A+B. The first contains exactly A 0s and B 1s. The second can be any pattern. Assuming all strings are equiprobable, what is the probability that my two strings match in at least x% of the positions?

Comment: Isn't $A+B = 100$?

Comment: Also question is not clear. Will you continue removing balls till the bag is empty and then we need to tell the probability that your answer was correct for exactly $X%$ of them.?

Comment: I will continue until the bag is empty. No, the answer is not 100%, but yes A+B = 100. I have to make a vector of [blue, red, blue, blue...], and then pull from the bag to generate an other vector like that, and then compare to see my accuracy. What is the probability my accuracy is at least X%?

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly how I should generate the first vector, but at the moment I am considering just generating "red" with probability A and "blue" with probability B.

Comment: If you know how many are red and you plan to draw them all, then with 100% confidence you know how many red balls you will draw.  Or, do you intend to adjust your guess as you draw and the ratios in the bag are changing?

Comment: Ugh. You all need this to be less abstract, apparently.

I have data from 108 Schizophrenic brains and 136 normal brains in a dataset. I extract features and run through a classifier. What are the odds my classifier gets 68% of the classifications (Schizophrenic vs Control) correct? How likely is that to just happen by chance?

Comment: We need to be less abstract!  Put the relevant data into your post!

Comment: The experimental data? It's gigabytes. Impossible.

Comment: If I understand this correctly (not at all certain) then you are asking:  "suppose I have two binary strings of length $A+B$, each of which contains exactly $A\;0's$ and $B\;1's$.  Assuming all such strings are equiprobable, what is the probability that my two strings match in at least $x\%$ of the positions."  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to put it.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't sound unreasonable.  Unfortunately, I don't have time to think about it right now.  If I may suggest...edit your post along the lines I suggested.  I think that should clear up the confusion.  If nobody else has settled it in the meantime, I'll take a look later on.

Comment: Oh, the second string isn't guaranteed to have exactly A 0s and B 1s. This complicates things.

Comment: Indeed.  What are $A,B$ numerically, do you know?  If, say, $A$ was more than $68\%$ of the total then I'd just guess $0$ for all slots and I'd be guaranteed a win.  I think you need to be as precise as possible.  Abstract is no problem, just be clear and complete.

Comment: You don't get to guess the second string intelligently and "win". Yes, the classifier tries to do that, but this is purely about how likely its results are if there were no intelligence behind it, i.e. it's trying to classify based on nonsense. (I fear my features are so stepped on that there's no signal left in the noise.)

For my purposes, let's say Control is 0 and Schizophrenic is 1, so there would be A = 136 0s and B = 108 1s in the first string. The second string is only constrained to be of length 244.

Comment: This seems ill posed.  If I know the prior distribution, then my guess should reflect that knowledge.  Say $A$ were $99\%$ of the data.  Then if you make me guess blindly then obviously I'll be wrong a huge percent of the time.  That proves nothing.

Comment: In any case, I think there is an interesting question buried here somewhere.  Like I say, though, I can't think about it now.  Please try to clarify the question as much as possible.

Comment: What I want is a notion of how intelligent the classifier is by knowing how likely a result of 68% is to arise by chance. It's really more combinatorial than probibalistic, I guess. Of all possible second strings, how many match at >=X% of locations? Divide that number by 2^N, and I have my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all strings are equiprobable for the second one, the first doesn't matter.  You are taking the bitwise XOR of the strings and asking if you have $x\%\ 0$'s in the result with each bit having equal chance to be $1$ or $0$.  So just look at the chance you have at least $\frac x{100}(A+B)\ 0$'s in a string of $A+B$ bits.  This is a cumulative binomial distribution.  You can use the normal approximation to ease the calculation.

Comment: I think this will work.

Comment: 68%*244 = 166.

sum n = 166 to 244 (244 choose n)*(0.5^244) = 9.03586 * 10^-9.

integral from 0.68 to infinity (1/(2*61*pi) * exp(-(x-122)^2/(2*61))) dx

Comment: Using the normal approximation, $$np = \mu = 122$$ and $$np(1-p) = 61 = \sigma^{2}$$. Integrating from 0.68 to infinity yields 0.051. That's very different from 10^-8. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Ah. I see. I had it wrong. $$integral from 166 to infinity (1/sqrt(2*61*pi) * exp(-(x-122)^2/(2*61))) dx = 8.8*10^-9$$
Evidently my result is significant. My classifier is better than random in a more rigorous sense; there is some signal left in the noise.